# Performance in different variable scopes?

Tags: ruby, performance, compiler-construction

I wrote a simple test case:

```
$g = 10
def fun_g a
  a += $g
end

def fun_l a
  l = 10
  a += l
end

def fun_gl a
  $gl = 10
  a += $gl
end

def test fun
  t = Time.now

  (10 ** 6).times { |n|
    method(fun).call(n)
  }

  puts(Time.now - t)
end

test :fun_g
test :fun_l
test :fun_gl
```

The result is something like below. It seems that the first function `fun_g` is the fastest, and the `fun_gl` is the slowest.

```
1.249626
1.268355
1.30267
```

But I also get result that indicates the `fun_l` is the fastest.

```
1.27436
1.25794
1.303973
```

Theoretically, which one should be the fastest?
What if I change the example to a compiled language, will the result still be the same? Will the compiler optimize the local variables to global ones?

Comment: All this benchmark measures is the performance of the garbage collector and the reflection system. Creating and destroying 1 million `Method` objects and reflectively calling them is orders of magnitude more expensive than a simple variable reference and a `Fixnum` addition.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So that's why I ask for a theoretically explain, I know my test is not accurate. I present them here to show my though, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have converted this to use the STDLIB `benchmark` and got this result

```ruby
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 10 ** 7
$global = 0
local = 0
@instance = 0
Benchmark.bmbm(8) do |x|
  x.report('global') {iterations.times { $global } }
  x.report('local') {iterations.times { local } }
  x.report('instance') {iterations.times { @instance  } }
end
```

The results:

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
global     1.580000   0.010000   1.590000 (  1.600952)
local      1.540000   0.000000   1.540000 (  1.555683)
instance   1.600000   0.000000   1.600000 (  1.642781)
----------------------------------- total: 4.730000sec

               user     system      total        real
global     1.560000   0.000000   1.560000 (  1.575711)
local      1.540000   0.000000   1.540000 (  1.547040)
instance   1.600000   0.010000   1.610000 (  1.618772)
```

Using `benchmark-ips` gem:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

$global = 0
local = 0
@instance = 0

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('global') { $global }
  x.report('local') { local }
  x.report('instance') { @instance }
  x.compare!
end
```

Gives the following report on my machine at this time, and perhaps gives a more easily read comparison:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
              global    34.310k i/100ms
               local    34.461k i/100ms
            instance    34.383k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
              global      3.154M (± 2.9%) i/s -     15.748M
               local      3.205M (± 4.5%) i/s -     15.990M
            instance      3.153M (± 3.1%) i/s -     15.747M

Comparison:
               local:  3205049.9 i/s
              global:  3153595.5 i/s - 1.02x slower
            instance:  3152813.3 i/s - 1.02x slower
```

You had compared only local variable and global variables but neglected instance variables.

There is very negligible difference in any, which is actually a good thing.

I am not sure this answers your question, but hope it helps.

Comment: All this benchmark measures is the performance of the garbage collector and the reflection system. Creating and destroying 1 million `Method` objects and reflectively calling them is orders of magnitude more expensive than a simple variable reference and a `Fixnum` addition.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I agree with you. I actually am thinking that timing access of variables is a moot point. If it is more than negligible, then it is quite the real issue with a language.  I have isolated the tests to the subject matter at hand... which is to say only accessing the global, local and instance variables. Thanks @JörgWMittag.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are right. Why not teach me a right way to test it, or the theory behind it?

Comment: See my current test @YadSmood it concentrates only on accessing those variables.